# Create a form with specific changed_data in django for testing purposes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I've overridden `ModelAdmin.save_model` in order to trigger a task if a certain field was changed. Basically something like:

```py
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    if "field_name" in form:
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: trigger_task())
```

Now I'm trying to write a unit test that checks whether this task will be triggered in response to the field change. Only I'm having a hard time creating a form whose `changed_data` will contain that field.

My test is currently something like:

```py
@patch(...)
def test_task_should_trigger_if_field_changed(self, mocked_task):
    admin = MyAdmin(model=MyModel, admin_site=AdminSite())
    form = MyForm({"field_name": "changed"}, initial={"field_name": "initial"})
    ...
    admin.save_model(request=MagicMock(), obj=my_model, form=form, change=False)
```

The test above won't create a `form` whose `changed_data` contains `field_name` and the task will never be triggered. At this point, I'm considering creating a mocked object that will return that famed `form.changed_data["field_name"]` but I'm wondering if I'm missing something or is there a simpler way of doing this.

EDIT: I'm testing something else in that test but this is currently a blocker unless I mock it.